# Sound is playing both from speakers and headphones, no options in AlsaMixer on ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Ive connected second monitor and some cheap Phanasonic headphones to my ThinkPadE495. When I play any sound on my device either test sound in sound settings or Youtube video sound is coming both from headphones and laptop speakers. I`ve searched on StackExchange for a bit, everyone recommends to manually mute speakers via AlsaMixer, but I dont have such options.
[AlsaMixer with only "PCM" device available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFrta.png)

Comment: Have you tried `pavucontrol` ; ie. pulse audio volume control... it's where I'd head well before trying the *old* ALSA tools

Comment: Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community. Just to confirm the obvious: have you double-checked and made sure that the headphones are securely plugged into the audio port? I have sometimes plugged in a headset, and though it output audio, it wasn't enough to switch audio devices in the OS.

Comment: Yeah, I`ve checked it. I have Ubuntu and Windows installed in double boot and those exact headphones work with windows just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@guiverc](https://askubuntu.com/users/469152/guiverc)

```
pavucontrol
```

worked for me.

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
sudo pavucontrol
```

and then drag volume of the second output to 0%