# Can't switch audio output to built-in speakers on Ubuntu laptop (headphone jack plug broken and stuck)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I was using headphones with my laptop (running Ubuntu 22.04), the cable broke and small part of the connector stayed stuck inside the jack plug. I'm having trouble switching the audio output to my speakers.

Before my headphones broke, the audio output would automatically switch to the speakers when I unplugged the headphones. But now that the headphone jack is stuck, the laptop keeps playing sound through the broken headphones and I can't find a way to switch to the speakers.

In the Sound settings, there is only one option available - the broken headphones. I have also tried using `pavucontrol` that I found from this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1454488/sound-is-playing-both-from-speakers-and-headphones-no-options-in-alsamixer-on-u), but in my list of audio output, I have `speakers (unavailable)`.

Is there a way to manually switch the audio output to the built-in speakers, even though they are not listed as an option in the Sound settings? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to take if for repair. It is a hardware problem. As long as there is a bit of metal stuck in the connector it wont be fixed.

Comment: Try to add line to /etc/pulse/default.pa `set-card-profile <card index> output:analog-stereo`. Replace <card index> with your sound cards index from the output of `pacmd list-cards`.